# All the connections are in use: Execution halted

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I'm using `getYahooData()` function in **TTR** package quite intensely.

I have this piece of code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(symbol)){
    tryCatch(prices <- getYahooData(symbol$symbol[i], from, to, freq="daily", 
                                    type="price"), 
             warning=function(e) continue <- 0)
    if (continue==0) next
}
```

This loop is long I get this error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : all connections are in use Calls: tryCatch
>   ... doTryCatch -> getYahooData -> getYahooData -> read.table -> file
>   Execution halted

What can I do?

**UPDATE:**

If i use closeAllConnections() I get:

```
 I get: *** caught segfault *** address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped' Traceback: 1: getConnection(set[i]) 2: close(getConnection(set[i])) 3: closeAllConnections() aborting ...
```

Comment: non-reproducible on my system. What's the symbol vector you used? try `dput(symbol)` and give us the output.

Comment: how did you reproduce it? i use this function to download around 3000 stocks prices

Comment: first, I did not. Until I figured out that I must have something with an error and a warning. So I solved your problem, but you deserve some serious spanking for the code you posted. ;)

Comment: could you provide info about your OS and R version?

Comment: @Joris Ubuntu - R version 2.12.1

Comment: Thx. I reported this on R-devel, so they can use that information.

Comment: @Joris, ok perfect.... I wrote you below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First : do not ever in your life use that continue construct again. It's of no use. `tryCatch()` *will* continue if you defined a handler for an error or a warning. It will use that one instead of the "default" `error=function(e) stop(e)`. This one will stop your function. If you define a handler (either `warning=` or `error=` ), your script will not be stopped, so that continue is not necessary.

This said : The correct use of tryCatch in this case would be :

```
for(i in 1:nrow(symbol)){

tryCatch(prices <- getYahooData(symbol$symbol[i], from, to, freq="daily",
                                    type="price"), error = function(e){})

}
```

or, if you use it in a script and want to go to the next loop when an error occurs, you can simply use :

```
for(i in 1:nrow(symbol)){

    prices <- try(getYahooData(symbol$symbol[i], from, to, freq="daily",
                                    type="price"), silent=TRUE)

    if(inherits(prices,"try-error")) { next } # only true if an error occurs
    ... # rest of calculations
}
```

If you would have used this way of tryCatch or try, you wouldn't have had the problems you report here.

Now I could reproduce your case, if I use nonexistent symbols. Your erroneous use of `tryCatch()` function is causing you trouble. `read.table` returns an error (`Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection`). This is an **error**, not a warning. You get an additional warning saying that a 404 File not found was returned.

When a warning is issued together with an error, the handler function for the warning is dealt with first. That's because a warning has to be thrown before the function can be stopped. So it won't handle the error you get, <s>which means that the `on.exit(close(file))` in `read.table()` will not to be called. Hence, the connection is not closed correctly and still considered open, although it can't be found anymore by R (showAllConnections() shows nothing).</s> As the error is not dealt with, something goes wrong in the registration of the connections. As the connection couldn't be opened, the `on.exit(close(...))` will have no effect. `showConnections()` doesn't show the connection, but somehow R still thinks it's there.  Hence, all hell breaks loose and you crash your R.

*thanks for the corrections to @Tommy*

A simple code example to illustrate this :

```
myfun <- function(x){
   if(x>1) warning("aWarning")
   stop("aStop")
   x
}

tryCatch(myfun(0.5),
          warning=function(w)print("warning"),
          error=function(e) print("stop"))
[1] "stop"              

tryCatch(myfun(1.5),
          warning=function(w)print("warning"),
          error=function(e) print("stop"))
[1] "warning"
```

In summary :

- check the symbols you use. They're probably wrong.
- do not ever again use a warning handler if you expect errors.

And as an extra: your loop will only return the result of the last call, as you overwrite `prices` every time you go through the loop, in case you would have used correct symbols.

Edit : in case you want to continue the action

Comment: Joris - this is simply excellent work! If I could I would give +10.

Comment: I concur! ...but this indicates a huge flaw in the condition system! on.exit code must be guaranteed to ALWAYS be called, otherwise we're all in deep dodo...

Comment: Hmm I spoke too soon. It seems on.exit is, in general, run when a warning occurs and is caught? And btw, if the connection couldn't be opened, it shouldn't need to be closed either...

Comment: @Tommy I'm puzzled by it as well. I've been playing around, but I can't get to the core of the problem. It's something for the r-devel list, I'm busy with it.

Comment: Joris, I will run the script with your change on the tryCatch() function... I hope all will go well

Comment: @Joris, I don't understand one thing... If i don't "listen" to error exception it leave a connection opened?

Comment: @Dail : I don't know what's going wrong exactly. That's why I reported this to r-devel. The connection can't open, so it can't be closed. I guess some pointer to the connection exists that is either NULL or not initialized, but counted by R as a connection. Subsequently, when closeAllConnections() tries to access that memory, the segfault is thrown. But this is pure speculation.

Comment: Ok, what about using error "listener" as you wrote without closeAllConnections() at the end of the loop? SHould be ok?

Comment: @Joris i would like to jump it with i get a 404 error....like "continue" statement that the other programming languages have

Comment: @Dail : added an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 13):

Close some connections? Could be as easy as inserting `closeAllConnections()` at the end of that loop body.

Comment: do you mean put closeAllCOnnections() before the } of the loop ?

Comment: @ Dwin I get:  *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: getConnection(set[i])
 2: close(getConnection(set[i]))
 3: closeAllConnections()
aborting ...

Answer (score 9):

This is indeed a bug in the R source code regarding how connections are registered. I've posted some comments and a patch at the R Bugzilla site here: http://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14660. Joris' recommendations are sound. However, closeAllConnections() will also work, when the bug is fixed. (P.S. this is my first StackOverflow post. Pardon me if I've violated etiquette.)

Comment: Hardly a violation of any sort. Rather an example of highly desirable behavior. Identify a bug, report it and let people know. What could be better?

Comment: This was a bug that caused a repeatable memory violation. It was patched years ago. If you RTF bug report I linked here you will find the details.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in my past digging, someone mentioned that the use of a URL reference in a function like read.table.url() or url() invoked a somewhat buggy native R HTTP connector.  What has proven to work better for closure of connections on error is to explicitly call RCurl inside of a read.table(), or equivalent, function call.  For instance, this was giving me problems when a lot of HTTP errors accumulated:

```
result <- try ( DF <- read.table(con <- url(url), col.names=colNames),
silent=TRUE )
```

I have seen good results going with the RCurl variation, calling its getURL function:

```
result <- try ( DF <- read.table(textConnection(getURL(url)), col.names=colNames),
silent=TRUE )
```

This is while running R v2.15.3.